# In-app purchase refund in Amazon Live Testing tool

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, amazon-in-app-purchase

I've just started using Amazon Live App Testing tool. I can't find the way to "refund" tester for in-app purchase, so she can buy it again. Any ideas?﻿

Comment: Any update on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now there is no way to refund. User can cancel the subscription from their account.

[image]

Comment: Hi Saneesh, thank you for your reply! My in-app is of "entitlement" type and I don't see a way to cancel it or request refund from user (tester) account. Did I miss something or your solution works only for subscriptions?

Comment: My subscription is free for first one month. So it is showing "Turn off auto-renewal"(Updated screenshot in the answer). I am not sure Amazon provides any "cancel" button if the user is billed from first day.